# Load jQuery in a UserControl for SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, asp.net-3.5

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET Web Forms  to create a UserControl for a SharePoint (2010) site. The UserControl is loaded through SharePoint WebPart.

Everything works fine so far, but i need to use jQuery in my UserControl. So i downloaded jQuery and saved that in the following folder:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80
```

So i saved jQuery (for now) in the root directory.

In my UserControl code behind i added the following line in the `Page_Load` method:

```
ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "~/jquery.min.js", false);
```

But when i re-build my UserControl and load it on a SharePoint page it still says: `The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object`.

So basically jQuery isn't found.

Anyone any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this but you should save your jquery in 14 HIVE folder..

And after that it will load ..

Correct me if i am wrong

Thanks